# How can I use Extrude Faces along normals without making different sizes?

Tags: faces, normals, extrude

I'd like to make a low poly room in Blender, but when I try to add thickness to the wall and extrude the faces along the normals the smaller sized wall is thicker than the other. I want to make them the same size.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Thanks in advance,
Tobi
[image: Extrude Faces]

Comment: before extruding, go back in object mode and apply the scale (ctrl A), it's probably your problem

Comment: 2 things come to mind - First, make sure you apply scale to your object (Ctrl+a in object mode), this is to ensure uniform scale (can cause problems with extrusions, insets, etc...). Second, when you extrude along normals, a box pops up in the bottom left. In the options, make sure "Offset Even" is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Already comments are very usefull ... so just a tip.
You can start with **Solidify Modifier** with **Even Thickness** enabled.

[image]

Comment: when I add a Solidify modifier, this happens:
https://imgur.com/a/IAtDZoR

Comment: I haven't seen this before share file or check if there are not double vertices - in edit mode all selected Merge Vertices (M) by Distance. If it doesn't help share blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com